Solve $\dfrac{x-1}{2}\geq \dfrac{2}{3} \geq 1-\dfrac{x}{6}$

Solve $\dfrac{x-1}{2}\geq \dfrac{2}{3} \geq 1-\dfrac{x}{6}$

Multiply everything by $6$:
$3x-3 \geq 4 \geq 6-x$
Evaluate separately:
$3x-3 \geq 4 \Rightarrow 3x \geq 7 \Rightarrow x \geq \dfrac{7}{3}$
$4 \geq 6-x \Rightarrow x \geq 2$
So this makes no sense to me, and I'm not sure if the original inequality held given this result. Did I make a mistake somewhere?

Why doesn't it it make sense?  We need both $x\ge \frac 73$ and $x \ge 2$ so $x \ge \max(\frac 73, 2)= \frac 73$.  So long as $x \ge \frac 73$ you will always have $\frac {x-1}2\ge 23$ and you will always have $\frac 23\ge 1-\frac x6$.  In fact you will always have $\frac 23 >\frac {11}{18} \ge 1-\frac x6$.

Or put it another way.  If $x < 2$ then none of those inequalities are true.  If $2\le x < \frac 73$ then one of them ($\frac 23\ge 1-\frac x6$) is true but the other isn't.  And if $x \ge 2$ then both inequalities are true.  It works out just fine.

Or a third way.  If $x < 2$ then $\frac {x -1}2 < \frac 23$ and $1-\frac x6 > \frac 23$.  If $2\le x < \frac 73$ then $\frac {x-1}2 < \frac 23$ and $1-\frac x6 \le \frac 23$.  And if $x\ge \frac 73$ then $\frac{x-1}2 \ge \frac 23 \ge 1-\frac x6$.  It's all good, man.

I think what is perplexing you is you are expecting that because the question has been stated and a neat single line inequality, $a < b < c$, you expect the answer to do, $m < x < n$. so as well.  And that'd be the case if the the coefficients of $x$ were the same sign.  But as the neat single line inequality, $a< b< c$ is actually two inequalities $a< b$ and $b < c$ and as $\frac 23 \ge 1-\frac x6$ involves a negative coefficient to the $x$ so the inequality sign will "flip".  We are going to end up with two inequalities $m < x$ and $n < x$ that don't telescope.
That's fine.  If you have $x \ge \frac 73$ and $x \ge 2$ you still find the case where they are both true.  Namely:  $x \ge \max (\frac 73, 2) =\frac 73$.
Now it might seem, gee we never needed the first inequality $\frac {x-1}2 \ge \frac 23$ at all, did we? And it's true in the final answer we didn't.  But think of it this way:
There are two critical values where these expression change.  At $x=\frac 73$ we have $\frac {x-1}2 =\frac 23$ and at $x = 2$ we nave $1-\frac x6 = \frac 23$.
This breaks the real line into three segments.
Case 1:  $x < 2$.  Then $\frac {x-1}2 < \frac 23$ and $\frac 23 < 1-\frac x6$ so $\frac{x-1}2 < \frac 23 <  1-\frac x6$ and the problem is false.
Case 2:  $2 \le x < \frac 73$ then $\frac {x-1}2 \ge \frac23$ but $1-\frac x6 > \frac 23$ so the problem is false.  We don't really have a way to compare $1-\frac x6$ with $\frac {x-1}2$ but it doesn't matter the problem is false. (Actually we can compare.  If $2\le x < \frac 94$ then $1-\frac x6 > \frac {x-1}2 \ge \frac 23$ and if $\frac 94 \le x < \frac 73$ the we have $\frac {x-1}2 \ge 1-\frac x6 > \frac 23$.  But we weren't asked to go into that much detail.  The problem still is false.)
Case 3:  $2 \ge \frac73$.  then $\frac {x-1}2 \ge \frac23$ and $1-\frac x6 \le \frac 23$ and so $\frac {x-1}2 \ge \frac 23 \ge 1-\frac x6$ and the problem is ... TRUE.

For the three cases you mentioned, why did you choose $x<2, 2 \leq x < \frac{7}{3}, 2 \geq \frac{7}{3}$? Were these arbitrary or is there a reason? For example I would've chosen $x\leq 2, 2 < x < \frac{7}{3}, 2 \geq \frac{7}{3}$

I chose those because the agreed with the given inequalities.  $\frac {x-1}2 \ge \frac 23 \iff x \ge 2$ so I wanted to divide the real numbers into $(-\infty, 2)$ and $[2, \infty)$.  And $\frac 23 \ge 1-\frac x6 \iff x\ge \frac 73$ so I wanted to divide $[2,\infty)$ into $[2,\frac 73)$ and $[\frac 73,\infty)$.  It doesn't really matter where you include the "critical points" $x=2$ and $x = \frac 23$, so long as you note the system is true for $x=\frac 73$ and false for $x = 2$.

You basically want to find an $x\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $3x-3\geq 4$
and $4\geq 6-x$ both hold. I plotted both inequalities for you :
See $6-x\leq 4$ iff $x\geq 2$ but then $3x-3\leq4$ so this x won't do. As you found when $x\geq \frac{7}{3}$ then both inequalities will be satisfied which is also clear from the plot above. When you deal with such inequalities you can break them up in pieces and find an x which satisfies all inequalities.
